# Cannot find element for Selenium on a website on Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to create a Selenium automation in Python but I can't for the life of me figure out where the xpath/class/id/etc for the username or password fields are. I'm trying to work with this page [here](https://www.marvel.com/signin?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marvel.com%2Fredeem). It is the login page to redeem Marvel comic codes. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `iframe`, so you would have to switch the *driver focus* to iframe first and then can interact with username and password field :

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.marvel.com/signin?referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marvel.com%2Fredeem")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "disneyid-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='email']"))).send_keys('some username')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']"))).send_keys('some password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[ng-click]"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```